# How to set Widget to QAbstractTableModel data without setIndexWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to insert a QRadioButton in the first row and first column of QTableView. I can do it with setIndexWidget. Is it possible to set Widget data in QAbstractTableModel.data?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, datas, parent=None):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._datas = datas

    def data(self, index, role=None):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._datas[index.row()][index.column()]

    def rowCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return len(self._datas)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return len(self._datas[0])

class MyQTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyQTableView, self).__init__(parent)
        radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton()

class MainQ(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainQ, self).__init__()
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('OK')
        self.view = MyQTableView(self)

        radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton()
        self.model = TableModel([(radio,), ("b",), ("c",)])
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.ly = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.ly.addWidget(self.view)
        self.setLayout(self.ly)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
table = MainQ()
table.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: While there *could* be ways to achieve it, that wouldn't advisable, since the data of a model should theoretically be serializable, and I'm under the impression that you might be having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you please try to clarify why you need to do this?

Comment: @musicamante Tks very much for u answer, If so, to insert the Widget into the tableview, it's not necessary to pass the model, right? 
I originally wanted to directly insert the Widget through the initialization data method.
In this case, mode.data() will only be called three times.
But if I call the setIndexWidget() later, The mode.data() will be called three times again.

Comment: as already requested, please try to explain what you're trying to achieve. Your last comment is very confusing and, if I may, it also leads me to think that you don't really understand how the model/view pattern works and what's the purpose of index widgets. A *model* is almost like a telephone directory: it just contains arbitrary and selected data. The phone book is a *view* (just like the table), and your call to the telephone company is a possible "editor" to tell the company that you changed address. Your call won't be on the directory, the data (your new address) will.

Comment: Hi @musicamante, My understanding is that QAbstractTableModel.data uses rowCount and columnCount to control the representation of the view.
Let me change the way of expressing the problem:
In my Case ,According to Model/View Architecture, how can I present my data and Widget in the view correctly?

Comment: No. The model contains *all* data, the row/column count only return the *extent* of the model, it does **not** "control" the representation of the view. Then it's up to the view to *decide* what to display and how, *based* on the row/column count (for example, by hiding a complete column as in your other question). I have to ask you again to try to explain what you're trying to achieve: the question at the end of your last comment is confusing, and it's not clear what is the problem about the requests to `data()`. I believe you're still a bit confused about the M/V pattern.

Comment: Models are completely **independent** from views. They should only provide the data and the methods to change the contents and layout. They should not know *anything* about the view (or the *views*). Furthermore, a "view" is not always a specific visual element (like tables, lists or trees): it's just something that *represents* the data to the user, *in any way*. For instance, QDataWidgetMapper **is** a view (and, coincidentally, you can set a delegate for it). Even a text-to-speech engine that shouts out a list of elements in a model can be considered a "view".

Comment: That said, it's *not* "forbidden" to add arbitrary objects to a Qt model, but considering the general purpose of those models (which should provide serialization), attaching widgets to the model is not generally done. So, the question remains: why do you need to add widgets directly to the model? What are you trying to achieve? What is the *final purpose* of your program? What aspects of `setIndexWidget` don't fit your needs and lead you to look for alternatives?

Comment: Thank you for bringing the problem to me attention. My misunderstanding of rowCount and columnCount may mislead you again，I later found out that they only control the display of the current view range.
My real intention is：
  I need to aggregate data in QWidgetView, so I added a radio button to each row of view to control the starting index of the Row that needs to be started. My initial idea was to load all Widgets and data at once, because of the use setIndexWidget needs to traverse the data one more time.

Comment: There is a better solution instead of QRadioButton, such as using DecorationRole?